# Google Sheets Link and pass data to another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-macros

I have the following sheet

[image]

What I want is to have a link on the invoice numbers, so when any of the numbers are clicked the relevant data is passed to another sheet to print in a specified format as follows

[image]

Note there that I only want to print the relevant data. I am doing this to get a printable invoice automatically.

If this can be achieved using app scripts then kindly point me to the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: In order to achieve your goal, as one of several methods, how about using Web Apps as the link URL? In this case, for example, about "123" of "invoice no", the link like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec?no=123` is used. When the link is clicked, the query parameter of `no=123` can be sent to Web Apps and process it you want. I posted it as a comment because I'm not sure whether this is the direction you want. If this is not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about this option. I wish to make it as simple a possible as non technical person will be using it. Keeping this question open to find another solution.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize that my comment was not useful for your situation.

Comment: You can have an item (get Invoice) in custom menu, which will trigger an event on click, and run a script -script will get the data from the current sheet (based on current selection range), insert a new sheet and populate the date in new sheet.

Comment: @krv With Apps Script, sure, you could store all your invoices in one Spreadsheet, in one Sheet and then with Apps Script just scroll to what ever Invoice you want. Is it interesting to you?

Comment: Autocrat, a google sheet add-on does what I want for now so closing this